# How to skip validation for Validation Engine plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I am using `jquery.validationEngin.js` plugin for the form validation. I have asp.net web form containing more submit buttons. They all are checking validations while posting data. I managed to skip the valition for some of those button by setting property`UseSubmitBehavior="false"` as refereed [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1953670.aspx).

However there are some control which does not have such property. Ultimately i want to ask here how can i skip the validation of form for some cases.

Comment: You Just dont need to declare class="validate[required]"   for those which validation isnt required

Comment: We are applying class on control other than buttons. Also i want to validate form on some button click and not on some other buttons

Comment: what are those controls that u are unable to skip validations for

Comment: @Vivekh: I think You misunderstood the question. there are all controls which requires validation however if there is button say cancel; it also check for validation rather than going to other page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the plugin documentation [here](http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/#actions/detach) I manage to the things right. You have to simply detach the validation plugin wherever you feel unwanted. I have made below function and call it before performing any action.

```
function ByPassValidations() {
    $("#formId").validationEngine('detach');
    return true;
}
```